# postgis and osm2pgsql: authentication failed

Tags: postgis, osm2pgsql

Id like to import osm into my postgis to use it with qgis. I followed exactly these instructions: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PostGIS/Installation

At step #Activate_PostGIS:

```
psql --username=gisuser --dbname=gis --command="\d"
```

This error occured:

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "gisuser"
```

(Same after importing my *.osm by doing this:

```
osm2pgsql -s -U gisuser -d gis path-to-file.osm
```

Error:

```
Error: Connection to database failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "gisuser"
```

I have no idea what to do, so im asking here.

Using xubuntu 12.10, postgres 9.1.11

Comment: add a user with password for postgis. http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_tut01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how is in your **pg_hba.conf** but I believe you use the `peer` authentication method. *(This method is only supported on local connections.)*

Because this doesn't work, try to change it to `md5` *("md5" is preferred since it sends encrypted passwords)*, like this:

[image]

and restart your database server.

*References:*

- `pg_hba.conf` inside comments;
- [PostgreSQL Authentication Methods](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html)

Comment: It's not always needed to restart postgresql service after modifying pg_hba.conf - it's contents are read on the fly. Next time someone tries to login to db, changes in pg_hba.conf should be applied.

Comment: @SaultDon - In pg_hba.conf says that `This file is read on server startup and when the postmaster receives a SIGHUP signal.  If you edit the file on a running system, you have to SIGHUP the postmaster for the changes to take effect.  You can use "pg_ctl reload" to do that.` Also on Wikipedia says that `The SIGHUP signal is sent to a process when its controlling terminal is closed.`

Comment: @SorinCălinică Neat. On a windows and linux PC, I've noticed these changes take effect immediately. But if it recommends to restart, then sure.

Comment: @SaultDon - I think, also, that your observation it is very important to know, mainly for a production server.

Comment: @SorinCălinică Could it be a bug? I can ask maybe on the IRC.